# Using conditional 'ば'

Tags: grammar, conditionals

[In this thread on japan-guide.com](http://www.japan-guide.com/forum/quereadisplay.html?0+27379), we find two seemingly contradictory statements concerning the conditional particle `ば`.

One poster states:

If A & B are the same subject, B must be non-volitional. Otherwise, B can be volitional, e.g.:

> [日本]{にほん}へ[行]{い}けば、[富士山]{ふじさん}がみられます

Another poster states that `ば` were used in expressions which reflect the speaker's will, judgment, permission, view, order or request, e.g.:

> [安]{やす}ければ、[買]{か}います
> [早]{はや}く[起]{お}きられれば、 [電話]{でんわ}をかけます/します

How do we reconcile these two statements?

Both do seem correct on their own.

Comment: "An opinion"?  "Another"?  What are your sources?

Comment: [Google never ceases to surprise me.](http://www.japan-guide.com/forum/quereadisplay.html?0+27379) Just search that thread for "reflect the speaker's will," and "If A & B are the same subject" to locate the relevant posts.

Answer (score 1):

Gramatically there is no restriction on volatility.
Practically, however, the first presenter’s rule is partially correct.

If you say:

> × 早く起きれば、電話します。

Japanese listener thinks:

> It is you that decides whether to wake up early or not.
>   Thus, you must know whether you will make a call or not.

On the other hand:

> ⚪︎ 早く起き**られれ**ば、電話します。

is acceptable, because you don't know yet whether you can wake up early or not.

Comment: So,would '早く起くなら,電話します' be better  - turning the driving clause to be an assumption rather than a condition?

Comment: @IUnknown “起きるなら” will arise same feeling as “起きれば”.

Comment: So that would be incorrect too.